# Undeclared namespace prefix "app" (for attribute "cardCornerRadius") Android?

Tags: android

> Undeclared namespace prefix "app" (for attribute "cardCornerRadius")
> at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [16,38]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFC6C6"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't see any problems in the XML - do you see this error when you try to build and run the app, or just as highlighted red text in Android Studio? If the latter, have you tried the Invalidate Caches & Restart then a clean build?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first 2 lines from the Cardview. Then go to the last line and press Alt+Enter and choose the first option from the popup to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have these definitions (helped me in the same situation)

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```